# JBOSS Setting http.proxyHost and http.proxyPort in standalone.xml

Tags: configuration, jboss, http-proxy

I am using JBOSS 7.1.1 for running my applications. 
I have to configure proxy hosts to access my server. I tried setting up the changes in standalone.xml file

I added it as

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="http.proxyHost" value="My proxy Host here"/>
    <property name="http.proxyPort" value="My proxy Port here"/>
</system-properties>
```

But i added this while my server is running . I cant connect through the proxy still. the changes doesn't seems to be reflecting.

Does the server needs a restart for the changes to apply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any changes in standalone xml file to apply, we need to restart the server.
The changes got applied only after i made a restart.